# Firebreath plugin not loading in Firefox 20.0

Tags: firebreath

My environment: win8 64bit, vs2010, 
I follow every step in the [tutorial](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Creating+a+New+Plugin+Project) but my own dll plugin just can't be installed, I have also installed WiX toolsets and made a msi file,  but it simply do  not work...

(1) I do all the work with prompt(privileged  ) cmd.

(2)My files are shown in below 
[image]

(3)firefox about:plugins page do not contain my dll plugin after my msi file installed..

(4) failed ..

[image]

**So what is going on here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you building using the prep2010x64.cmd file (or a different x64.cmd file)? if so, that's likely your issue.  Many people, failing entirely to read the instructions on the firebreath website, mistakenly build using the x64 because they're running a 64 bit operating system.  thing is, the browsers like firefox still are 32 bit, so the plugin needs to be built 32 bit as well.

The next question, if that doesn't help, is whether or not the regsvr32 command succeeds when you run it on the .dll.

Clarification: You figured this out, but for future readers to be very clear:

> Do not use prep2010x64.cmd unless you can explain clearly why you need to -- and running a 64 bit OS does not count.  Most people want to use prep2010.cmd (or whichever year).

Comment: yes, I am using pre2010x64.cmd file, and  regsvr32 succeeded when I ran it on the .dll, I will try pre2010x64 later.

Comment: Thanks a lot @taxilian, you solved my problem. I was miss led because when I using prep2010.cmd file, there were some compiling errors... Anyway, thank you very much!